# I can't run the Android emulator. An error pops up

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't run the Android emulator in Android Studio. An error pops up:

> Android Emulator closed because of an internal error: gpu found.
> vendor id 1002 device id 0x6840
> checking for bad AND Vulkan driver version...
> amdv1k64.dlI not found.
> Checking for amdvlk32...
> amdv1k32. dlInot found.
> No bad AND Vulkan driver versions found.
> checking for bad vulkan-1.dll version...
> info on vulkan-1.dlI cannot be found, continue.
> emuglConfig_init: blackhsted=0 has_guest_renderer =1, mode: auto, option: (null)
> emuglConfig_init: auto-selected host based on conditions and UI preference 0
> emuglConfig_init: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
> Deciding if aDirectNemNulkan should be enabled. Selected renderer: 1 API level: 28 host GPU blacklisted? 0
> Host GPU selected, not enabling Vulkan because either API level is Not enabling Vulkan here (feature flag may be turned on manually)

Screenshot: [Android emulator, error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWHZN.png)

How to fix it?

Comment: Your GPU appears to be a Radeon 7600M, which according to [this page](https://community.amd.com/t5/blogs/radeon-gpus-are-ready-for-the-vulkan-graphics-api/ba-p/415008) doesn't have Vulkan support. Perhaps you can try to disable Vulkan for the Android Emulator? See https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#29.0.6-vulkan

Comment: Thanks. So I understand that I should create a file ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini and type :
    Vulkan = off
    GLDirectMem = off
?
This is what I did. The error doesn't appear, but Android won't boot. Only the Google logo is displayed.

Comment: Solved. I disconnected the docking station.